# Is there a way to make something similar to SELECT inside FROM in Neo4j like in SQL?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to make a query that gives me the list of people who reposted the posts of someone whose posts are the most likable.

It HAS to be one query, but I can make it only through two queries.
I've tried `OPTIONAL MATCH`, and the `CALL` clause, but it's still not working and I can't understand what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Here's my two queries:

1)

```
match (per1:Person)-[r1:LIKE]->(p:Post)<-[:CREATE]-(per2:Person)
return per2.name, count(r1) order by count(r1) desc limit 1
```

(I find that the author, whose posts get the biggest amount of likes, is Emily Douson, so I do the next step:)

2)

```
match (per:Person)-[:REPOST]->(p:Post)<-[:CREATE]-(per2: Person {name:"Emily Douson"})
return distinct per.name
```

The problem is that through `OPTIONAL MATCH` I can get the list of authors, but not the one author that I need to use.

My attempt to use `CALL` looked like:

```
call {
  match(per1:Person)-[r1:LIKE]->(p:Post)<-[:CREATE]-(per2:Person)
  return per2.FIO as personX, count(r1) as countL order by countL desc limit 1
}
with personX
match (per:Person)-[:REPOST]->(p:Post)<-[:CREATE]-(personX)
return distinct per.FIO
```

but I got the message:

```
Type mismatch: personX defined with conflicting type Boolean, Float, Integer, Number, Point, String, Duration, Date, Time, LocalTime, LocalDateTime, DateTime, List<Boolean>, List<Float>, List<Integer>, List<Number>, List<Point>, List<String>, List<Duration>, List<Date>, List<Time>, List<LocalTime>, List<LocalDateTime> or List<DateTime> (expected Node) (line 2, column 51 (offset: 212))
"match(per:Person)-[:REPOST]->(p:Post)<-[:CREATE]-(personX) return distinct per.FIO"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[r1:LIKE]->(:Post)<-[:CREATE]-(per2:Person)
WITH per2, COUNT(r1) AS cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
MATCH (per:Person)-[:REPOST]->(:Post)<-[:CREATE]-(per2)
RETURN DISTINCT per.name
```

Your first query needed to replace `RETURN` with `WITH`, so that the query did not end. And it also needed to pass `per2` to the second `MATCH`.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!!!! It works perfectly. Before I've tried similar queries but the syntax was wrong